# Error reading data through UART using peripheral library in PIC32?

Tags: pic, uart, error

I am trying to receive data using UART. I am using PIC32MX795F512L Micro Controller and using 32 bit peripheral library, so I using functions like putsUART or ReadUART1
Now in the code :

```
int main()
{
 OpenUART1( UART_EN | UART_NO_PAR_8BIT | UART_1STOPBIT  , UART_RX_ENABLE | UART_TX_ENABLE, (FPB/16/BAUDRATE)-1 );
 TRISDbits.TRISD5 = 0;
  while(1)
  {
    char RX_data;
    RX_data = ReadUART1();
    if(RX_data == '1')
    {
      LATDbits.LATD5 = 1;
      putsUART1("LED ON");
     }

     elseif(RX_data == 'q')
     {
       LATDbits.LATD5 = 0;
       putsUART1("LED OFF");
      }
   }
}
```

Now whenever I type 1 in the terminal led turns on but when I type q then led doesnt turns off. It works with digits but not with letters. Like if I do

```
elseif(Rx_data == '2')
```

Then it will work but not with

```
elseif(RX_data == 'q')
```

I don't know where I am missing the point. Please help.

Comment: Are you typing 'q' after typing 'l'? Or are you running the firmware again when typing 'q'?

Comment: yes I am typing q after 1

Comment: Maybe your terminal software sends a CR or LF character or both after the '1' character and that's why you loose the 'q' reading. Try and see if your terminal software has any option to automatically append CR/LF characters ta a transmission.

Comment: I am using docklight. Its not sending any CR LF

Comment: The code you just posted in your edit can't be compiling. 'rx' doesn't exist any more and there's no space between else and if. If this is directly from your code, which it should be, then you're just flashing your old binary over and over again

Comment: @Asmyldof that was by mistake. I have made the changes

Comment: Why are you declaring RX_data in an infinite loop?

Comment: Also, why don't you echo your read right back on the UART, so you can see what the problem is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you only want it to do one or the other, you need to modify your code as follows:

```
char RX_data = ReadUART1();
if(RX_data == '1')
{
    LATDbits.LATD5 = 1;
    putsUART1("LED ON");
}
else if(RX_data == 'q')
{
    LATDbits.LATD5 = 0;
    putsUART1("LED OFF");
}
```

If you logically step through your original code, you will see that when you enter 'q', it gets read and compared to '1', which it doesn't match, but then you *perform another read*, so you lose the 'q' that you'd already read.

Comment: I don't know why its not working, I have made it char acc to your answer. Everything seems perfect but still not getting the output

Comment: @user46573544 I just copied your code, which you say works ok for '1'. In fact, comapring an `int` with a `char` is valid, as long as the values do not exceed the range of `char`. I have amended my answer to be more specific but if this code doesn't work, you need to show a bit more of the context. I'm assuming that this is whithin a `while` loop. Make sure you only read once, then test all possibilities.

Comment: I didnt work. This is the only code I have. I am reading it once and then checking all the if else. There might be some other mistake.

Comment: @user46573544 So this piece of code is *not* inside a `while (1) { ... }` loop? Please amend your question and post the whole of your `main` function.

Comment: yes its inside while(1). I have edited my code

Comment: its working with 2 or any other digit but not working with letters. Strange
Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: @user46573544 Do you have Caps Lock on your keyboard? Maybe you're typing 'Q' instead of 'q'. If you have the hardware to debug, put a breakpoint after the read and see what you've read.

Comment: I have tried debuggin it. When I enter `1` its value shows `0x31` which acc to ascii is correct. Now when I enter `q` it shows `0xF1` which is not in ascii table. I also tried entering `2` so it shows `0x32` which means its `2` then I tried with `w`, it shows `0xE1` again not in ascii. Its not taking up letters. I dont know why. Any idea.!

Comment: If you see 0xF1 when you expect 0x71 ('q') it may be your parity, data bit size, or stop bits might be wrong. Check your configuration at both ends. Try reducing the baud rate too.

Comment: Everything is correct at both the ends

Comment: @user46573544 If so, then this is no longer a code problem, it's a hardware problem and possibly needs some debugging with a scope and/or logic analyser and, if necessary, a new question.

Answer (score 0):

If `ReadUART()` is giving you hard time. You can use other options like `getsUART1()`

The document says:

> Description: This function reads a string of data of specified length and stores it into
>   the buffer location specified.
>
> Include: plib.h
>
> Prototype: 
>       unsigned int getsUART1(unsigned int length,char *buffer, unsigned int uart_data_wait);
>
> Code Example: getsUART1(12, myBuffer, 123);

Or you could try putting values into the UART registers.